# Give 1 HTML option 2 values

Tags: html

```
<select name='input_1' id='input_13_1'  class='large gfield_select' tabindex='1' 
onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value='1' >100 Instagram Followers</option>
  <option value='2' >500 Instagram Followers</option>
  <option value='3' >1,000 Instagram Followers</option>
  <option value='4' >2,000  Instagram Followers</option>
  <option value='5' >5,000 Instagram Followers</option>
</select>
```

When an option is selected, customer clicks a button which redirects them to a PayPal payment page. Problem I'm having is when for example option value='1' is purchased, I check the payment and the title says '1'. Is there a way to add a second value like;

```
<option value='1' & value='IG Followers' >100 Instagram Followers</option>
```

Just so it shows in my PayPal transaction that Instagram Followers was purchased. This is a wordpress theme which has no admin area, not sure why. I know nothing about HTML

This worked;

```
<option value='1; 100 IG FOllowers' >100 Instagram Followers</option>
```

Comment: Documentation: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside

Answer (score 0):

You can only set one value here, but do you need the 1, 2, 3, ... ? Why don't you replace the digits with the values you prefer ?

Comment: In the database table, the correct rows state 1,2,3 etc so I would need to change the value in the tabe>row to for example "IG Followers" aswell as in the .html file. But, when I do that, it errors. Only allowed numbers in the table>row

Comment: This worked;

    <option value='1; 100 IG FOllowers' >100 Instagram Followers</option>